# Why are all collisions removed using collisionFilter?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I have 4 bodies: 2 balls and 2 platforms.

I would like the balls to be able to overlap (no collision), but still collide with both platforms. I've read through the official [Matter.js Documentation](http://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#property_collisionFilter) and played with the [`collisionFilter` demo](http://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#collisionFiltering), but still can't get a grasp of achieving what I need.

```
let defaultCollision = 0x0001;
let ballCollision = 0x0002;
let holderCollision = 0x0004;
let floorCollision = 0x0008;

ball1 = Bodies.circle(...
  collisionFiler: { mask: ballCollision }
  ...
});

ball2 = Bodies.circle(...
  collisionFiler: { mask: ballCollision }
  ...
});
// ^ these balls don't collide, which is good.

platform1 = Bodies.circle(...
  collisionFiler: { mask: holderCollision }
  ...
});

platform2 = Bodies.circle(...
  collisionFiler: { mask: floorCollision }
  ...
});
// I don't understand why the balls pass right through these platforms...
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out a solution!

In the Matter.js demo, I kept overlooking the different between `collisionFilter: { mask: defaultCategory | redCategory }` and `collisionFilter: { category: defaultCategory | redCategory }`. The difference was the `mask` and `category` rules.

To achieve the results of the balls overlapping, but colliding with the platforms:

```
let defaultCollisionCategory = 0x0001;
let ballCollisionCategory = 0x0002;


ball1 = Bodies.circle(...
  collisionFiler: { category: ballCollisionCategory }
  ...
});

ball2 = Bodies.circle(...
  collisionFiler: { mask: defaultCollisionCategory }
  ...
});

// You do not need to set either the collisionFiler mask or category, and the balls will collide with them
```

Hope this helps!